# Spring MVC and annotations, how to do a validator in the case of a form that will contain different fields depending of a combo box

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, annotations, hibernate-validator

I am trying to accomplish the following:

I have a form that starts with a combo box, let's say that the user will have to pick either "Student" or "Teacher".

Both "Student" and "Teacher" will have the same fields displayed in the form, but if "Teacher" is checked, I will have more fields being displayed (that are hidden at first and that I will show with jQuery when the user select "Teacher").

The problem is that I want those fields to be mandatory only if "Teacher" is selected.

I have no idea to manage that, I don't think it's gonna be possible using annotations such as:

```
@NotBlank
private String teacherCourse;
```

since this field will always be blank when the user will have selected the "Student" radio button.

Any idea? Can I do a custom validation method and how?

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript or JQuery for front side validation... depending upon your combo box value. If it's a teacher or student

```
function validate(){

 var combox_value = document.getElementbyID("combo_box").value;

     if(combox_value == "Teacher"){
     //Validate for Teacher fields
        var input_text1 = document.getElementbyID("input_text"2).value;
        if(input_text1=="" || input_text1==null){
        alert("Field cannot be empty");
        return false;
        }
        return true;
     }
     else if(combox_value == "Student"){
     //Validate for Student fields
        var input_text2 = document.getElementbyID("input_text2").value;
        if(input_text2=="" || input_text2==null){
        alert("Field cannot be empty");
        return false;
        }
        return true;
     }

}
```

For JQuery try these links for live examples...
http://speckyboy.com/2009/12/17/10-useful-jquery-form-validation-techniques-and-tutorials-2/
http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/form/form3.php
http://www.camcloud.com/blog/jquery-form-validation-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

I've taken two approaches with this in the past.

Use an enum field on the submission to determine which type of validation to perform.  This is flexible and allows for any number of custom validation methods.

An alternative is to use a base command object which both student and teacher classes extend. This allows both types to extend and override validation and fields. This requires that separate methods are used to bind each type.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [validation groups](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html/validator-usingvalidator.html#validator-usingvalidator-validationgroups) to differentiate between constraints applying to both entities and those applying to only one of them:

```
public interface TeacherConstraints {}

@NotBlank(groups=TeacherConstraints.class)
private String teacherCourse;
```

When validating your object, specify the group to validate depending on the type selected in your combo box:

```
//teacher
Set<ConstraintViolation<Object>> violations = validator.validate(object, TeacherConstraints.class);

//student
Set<ConstraintViolation<Object>> violations = validator.validate(object, Default.class);
```